# add a version to script tag prevents it to be cached

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a script tag like this:

```
<script src="/dashboard/js/script.js?version=1"></script>
```

But for some reason it never cache, it always being downloaded !

I thought it should download first and  after this, as long as it's the version=1 it should be cached , right ?

What I'm missing ? How can I cache version 1 script to the browser cache ?

Comment: Did you by chance disable the cache entirely in the developer tools that you are using?

Comment: Are you sure it is cached when you do not put any version?

Comment: No disable cache is unchecked in chrome developer tool

Comment: When I remove the version I loads from cache again !

Comment: what are the values of cache-control in your response headers for both js with version and without version ?

Comment: FYI putting a version or better still, a [checksum](https://imagekit.io/blog/ultimate-guide-to-http-caching-for-static-assets/#5-ensuring-fresh-content-is-served-fingerprints-in-the-urls) into the filename is a much better option for cache control

Comment: is the response status 304 by chance?

Comment: How are you caching the file? Can you include the cache headers you see in the network tab?

Answer (score 1):

are you checking the status code or also the extended information?

On following screenshots it looks like it is cached but still returns response 200

Check the timing waterfall. It will provide additional info.

[image: timing waterfall1]
[image: timing waterfall2]

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]